# How to delete everything from notepad++ file except a-zA-Z0-9?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have tried over and over to replace a file with a bunch of weird stuff to find only characters readable..

here's an example of the file

```
+­«›é¦$6ðbç›4;r6O–0µ<hiñÅÙuµN%\$Õnever in a million yearsþÈWèÁÆ§À[‰võ³°œ»ê"V5n¤ÉÂT‡«
```

See the word "hi" ? It has no "space" around it, therefore it should get deleted if possible, if not its ok!

But see the word "never in a million" - That should be there.. everything else should get deleted.

How?

Answer (score 0):

Using the regex mode, find:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|((?<![a-zA-Z0-9 ])[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,3}(?![a-zA-Z0-9 ]))
```

Replace with nothing.

The resulting text, given your sample, would be: `never in a million years`

Now notice this is not so simple, you have to set a threshold for what you will "consider as a word".
For instance, in the regex above, everything sequence of length **below 4 chars** is will be erased. (That's why `r6O` is removed.) So you can tune the regex for your needs by changing the second number in the `{1,3}` part. e.g. `{1,4}` will remove every sequence that has 4 or less chars, `{1, 5}` will remove those that have 5 or less and so on.

Try [that regex in an online tool](http://regex101.com/r/nD2mQ0/3), where you can fine tune it more easily.

Comment: Any idea how to get it to add 1 new line per match? insead of 100000 lines?

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by "add 100000 new lines per match"?

Comment: Try this regex: `([^a-zA-Z0-9 ]|((?<![a-zA-Z0-9 ])[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{1,3}(?![a-zA-Z0-9 ])))+` and replace it with a `\n`. Is this what you need? Btw, if it worked, you can accept the answer to let us know. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/219205